# How to retrieve date and time with user current timezone from database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing online mentor booking appointment system. Mentor from Singapore created their free time slot. Mentee from Myanmar will book to meet with mentor from Singapore. How to search with Myanmar timezone in tables date and time created with Singapore timezone. Eg. Mentors from Singapore create 15-11-2022 1:00AM. Mentee from Myanmar search this date and time from table but this time not found in tables. Because Myanmar's timezone is 1 hours and a half behind Singapore. 15-11-2022 1:00AM in Singapore, 14-11-2022 11:30PM in Myanmar. So how can I search for different timezone in the table?

I tried for it but I am not ok. Could anyone please tell me the best one way? Thanks.

Comment: please show what you tried.  also please show output of `show create table yourtablename;` for the table with rows created with Singapore timezone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Option1:** Change UTC to user's timezone on frontend.

**Option2:** Change on backend.

[How to manage timezone in Laravel](https://brainlet.medium.com/manage-timezones-in-laravel-utc-to-users-timezone-305274278096)